# Python - drop rate in games, random with assigned probability

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I 30 numbers
I need to assign them random but with drop chances
Ex: There's 2% for number 1, 1.5% for number 2, 1.1% for number 3, 1.7% for number 4 etc...
I'm genereting random numbers with this

```
from random import randint
import string
import random

print(randint(1,30)) # generates random number from 1 to 30
```

But need to assign probability for every number
I don't mind manually assigning percentage to every number
Just need to know how to assign percentage to a random number

Answer (score 3):

```
from numpy.random import choice
items = "common","uncommon","rare","super rare"
probabilities = [0.5,0.35,0.1,0.05]
N_TESTS = 10
for i in range(N_TESTS):
    print choice(items,p=probabilities)
```

you could then abstract this out to where each of those was a "category"

```
items = {"common":["fork","spoon","twig"],"uncommon":["rake","shovel","coal"],"rare":["knife","mixing bowl"],"super rare":["dragon tears","some money","flaming sword"]}
probabilities = {"rare":0.1,"super rare":0.05,"common":0.5,"uncommon":0.35}
item = choice(items[choice(probabilities.keys(),p=probabilities.values())])
print "You Loot:",item
```

Comment: How to make numbers not repeat. in result sometimes I'm getting 1 item twice

Answer (score 2):

This would work it allows you to choose the numbers and your probabilities

```
from scipy import stats
numbers = (1,2,3)
probability = (0.02, 0.015, 0.011)
test1 = stats.rv_discrete(name='test1', values=(numbers, probability))
test1_results = test1.rvs(size=30)
```

Here is how to get non-repeating numbers

```
count = 0
list = []
while count < 31:
    test_result = test1.rvs(size=1)
    if test_result not in list:
        list.append(test_result)
        count += 1
```

Comment: any possible way to make test1_results not repeating numbers? I tried test1_results != test1_results. not working

Comment: There isn't anything built into scipy.rvs, but you could create a list and do '''x = test1.rvs(size=1) if x not i in list: list.append(x)''' Then just write that into a loop until you have your 30 numbers. But if you are generating a list of the numbers 1-30 in a random order each time you might as well just shuffle a list of your 30 numbers